# How can I separate a words not know how many are there

Tags: python

How can I make the words separate when I do not know the length of the word?

```
Split the string into the specified number of sub segments where each sub
segment consists of a contiguous block of characters. Finally, reverse all the sub segments divided by
separator characters to build a new String and display it.
```

For example, If the input is:

```
String = appleisgreat
ss =4
separator: ,
```

I want to get the result of:

```
eat,sgr,lei,app
```

I have done this far, and I am having trouble dividing the words into specific sub segments.

```
string = input("Enter a stirng:")
ss = eval(input("Enter the number of sub segments:"))
separator = eval(input("Enter the separator:"))

worldlist = list(string)
separate = worldlist/[ss]
print(separate)
```

Comment: What is `ss = 4`? Are you supposed to split it into 4 separate strings? What is the desired result, a string or a list? Does it have to be in reverse?

Comment: Yes. Actually I don't know if I need to leave it as string or list in order to get the result. ss = 4 is that I need to separate a sentence evenly into 4 and put a separator between those worlds. For example is separator is ,  the result should be eat,sgr,lei,app

Comment: I also cannot figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  Could you `edit` to give us more clarification? Also, you misspelled "Enter a string".

Comment: Why would it not be: app, lei, sgr, eat ?

Comment: So count the number of letters in the sentence, divide by 4.  That gives the number of letters in a group.  Then tear off that many letters to put into each group.

Comment: `','.join([s[i:i+len(s)/ss] for i in range(0,len(s),len(s)/ss)][::-1])`

Comment: @mshsayem What is s in your code?

Comment: `s` is the `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the length of the word.
You know the length of the "sentence", or starting string: `len(string)` or `len(sentence)`.
(I avoid using `string` or `String` as var names, as they are reserved in many languages as data types).

You know the number of words you need, as `ss` (I'll be calling this `wordLength`).

The length of each word will be `len(sentence) // wordLength` - if they are guaranteed to be evenly divisible.
Otherwise, use:

```
wordLength = len(sentence) // wordLength

# // TRUNCATES, so if if its not evenly divisible, 
# the "fractional" number of letters would get left out.
# instead, let's increase all the other the word lengths by one, and now 
# the last word will have the remaining letters.
if len(sentence) % wordLength == 0:
    wordLength += 1
```

Now for the full code:

```
sentence = "appleisgreat"
ss = 4
seperator = ","

numWords = ss  # rename this variable to be descriptively consistent with my other vars

wordLength = len(sentence) // numWords   # use // to truncate to an integer
print(wordLength)
## 3

# create a list of ss strings, each of length segmentSize
wordlist = []
for wordNum in range(numWords):
  startIndex = wordNum * wordLength
  # print (startIndex, startIndex + wordLength) ## 0 3, 3 6, 6 9, 9 12
  word = sentence[startIndex : startIndex + wordLength]

  # since you want the list in reverse order, add new word to beginning of list.  
  # If reverse order is not required, `append` could be used instead, as wordlist.append(word)
  wordlist.insert(0, word)
print(wordlist)
## ["eat", "sgr", "lei", "app"]    

# lists are iterables, so `join` can be used here to "join" the strings together, seperated by "seperator"
result = seperator.join(wordlist)

print(result)
## "eat,sgr,lei,app"
```

Obviously, there are much more concise ways to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply importing [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html).

```
import textwrap
String ="appleisgreat"
ss=4
print (textwrap.wrap(String, ss-1))
```

Output:

`['app', 'lei', 'sgr', 'eat']`

Comment: How can I write if the String and ss is not stated?

Comment: Simply `import textwrap
print (textwrap.wrap("appleisgreat", 4-1))`

Answer (score 0):

Plain python:

```
>>> s = 'appleisgreat'
>>> ss = 4
>>> L = len(s)/ss
>>> separator = ","
>>> separator.join([s[i:i+L] for i in range(0,len(s),L)][::-1])
'eat,sgr,lei,app'
```

Better, make it a function:

```
def make_parts(s, ss, separator):
    # Find out what should be the length of each part
    L = len(s)/ss

    # range(0, len(s), L) is providing desired indices, e.g: 0, 4, 8, etc
    # s[i:i+L] is providing the parts
    # [::-1] is reversing the array
    # str join() method is combining the parts with given separator
    return separator.join([s[i:i+L] for i in range(0,len(s),L)][::-1])
```

And call like

```
>>> make_parts('appleisgreat', 4, ',')
'eat,sgr,lei,app'
```

Comment: If i run this I get the rusult of <function make_parts at 0x03583270> , not a word...

Comment: But I showed you the calling which is showing results. I guess you may have forgotten to _call_ the function.

Comment: what do you mean by call the function? sorry, I am just starting to learn coding...

Comment: If you just type `make_parts` and press enter, it will show you `<function make_parts at 0x03583270>`. You have to invoke/call the function by `()` like in the above code. e.g. `make_parts('appleisgreat', 4, ',')`